# React Native Navigation in a if statement

Tags: javascript, react-native, navigation

Im making PIN code lock screen from react Native.
When the user entered correct pin it gives a alert "Login success"
When the user entered Wrong pin it gives a alert "Login failed"
if user entered PIN 3 times, I want to show a new screen.
so I write following code.

```
const checkPinCode = (a,b) => {
        if(arrayEquals(a,b)){
            alert("Login success")
          }else {
            alert(" Login Failed  ");
            seterrorCounter(errorCounter+1)
          }      
              if (errorCounter>=2){
                 //Navigation code 
                 () => navigation.navigate('Wait')
              }
}
```

But this does not do the job.
How can I navigate screens in a if else statement.
You can find the complete code and emulator here - https://snack.expo.dev/@codewithbanchi/pincode

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to:

```
const checkPinCode = (a,b) => {
        if(arrayEquals(a,b)){
            alert("Login success")
          }else {
            alert(" Login Failed  ");
            seterrorCounter(errorCounter+1)
          }      
              if (errorCounter>=2){
                 //Navigation code 
                 navigation.navigate('Wait') // remove () =>
              }
}
```

`() => navigation.navigate('Wait')` defines an unnamed function which es never called.

Comment: It is also not working my friend

Comment: Is the Wait screen within your StackNavigator?
Can you confirm that the line  navigation.navigate('Wait')  get executed?